# Checking if a value exists anywhere in range in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to check if the value of the cell **A1** exist anywhere 
from **sheet2!$A$2:$z$50**.

**IF the value exist** then return the value of the **1st Row** at the column where the match was found.

I tried:

- VLOOKUP
- HLOOKUP

but this functions are limited to check if match at a single row / column.

I was hoping for something like `=IF(A1,sheet2!$A$2:$Z$50,x1,FALSE)`
where x = the column where the match was found.

Is there something like that?

Comment: What sort of values are in row 1, text, numbers, dates? If they are numbers or dates then are they ordered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say *Sheet2* is like:

[image]

We want a formula on *Sheet1* that will return the value in the **header** row if that column contains a value to be found.  So if **A1** contains *Good Guy* then the formula should return *Victor Laszlo*
Put the following UDF in a standard module:

```
Public Function GetHeader(v As Variant, rTable As Range) As Variant
    Dim rHead As Range, rData As Range, WhereIsIt As Range
    Set rHead = Intersect(rTable(1).EntireRow, rTable)
    Set rData = Intersect(rTable.Offset(1), rTable)

    Set WhereIsIt = rData.Find(what:=v, After:=rData(1))
    If WhereIsIt Is Nothing Then
        v = "NOT FOUND"
        Exit Function
    End If

    GetHeader = Intersect(WhereIsIt.EntireColumn, rHead).Value
End Function
```

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

**=GetHeader(A1,Sheet2!A1:Z50)**

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

NOTICE:

We give the UDF the entire range **including the header row**  *(although the header row is excluded from the search)*

Answer (score 3):

An array formula like this would work

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> together

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:Z50,A1)>0,MIN(IF(A2:Z50=A1,ROW(A2:Z50),51)),"not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it if you use helper cells.

- In a helper row, use `MATCH()` in exact mode on each column to find the row index of the value in that column (if it exists). Wrap that in an `NOT(ISERROR())` to turn the result into true/false binary data. TRUE = match; FALSE = no match.
- Then use `MATCH()` again on the helper row, this time finding the first TRUE (i.e. matching) column; `MATCH()` will return the index of the column; then you can use `INDEX()` to look up the value of the first row in that column.

Answer (score 0):

My favourite for returning a value from a lookup sheet if a corresponding cell exists in both the lookup sheet and the sheet you want to enter data into is

```
INDEX('Sheet1'!I:I,(MATCH(D2,'Sheet1'!A:A,0)))
```

This is basically a more flexible version of a Vlookup or Match If formula. It say is you find a value matching what's in D2 in the Column A:A of Sheet 1 then return the corresponding value (from the same row) from Column I:I of Sheet 1.

I use this if I want to match data between two sheets e.g. pricing matched on product names or SKU.